# Photo and Video hosting on a shared server?

Tags: media, photo

I need to have several videos and photos on my website.
Primarily videos will range to more than a 100, and photos might be more than 10000. 
Since i am using a shared server hosting, i cant have enough space to upload them on my server nor will the performance graph be any good.
Hence i decided, i can upload the videos on YouTube and embed them in my web site.
However the problem is with the photographs. Which would be the best photostorage web service which can
A) Have a Web API
B)  Would have no need to create a badge or in any way not make it obvious that the photo is from some other source.
C) Unlimited Storage
D) High performance retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

picasa fit all your requirements except unlimited storage. but you have a lot of space and can buy extra storage for little money

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want a cloud based service or a self-hosted service?

If you want to self hosted an image hosting service, then you can check this project, [ImageS3](https://github.com/images3/images3-play), web admin console, REST api, and of course, no usage limitation on APIs.

If you wish to use the cloud based image hosting service, then you can use imgur.com, imageshack.com or www.imgix.com.